# Border-Radius not supported by Email Client

Tags: html, css, email

Border Radius is not supported by the email client (Outlook)

```
 <table bgcolor="#C0C0C0" style="border-radius: 25px; -moz-border-radius:25px; -webkit-border-radius: 25px; font-family:sans-serif;" width="50%">
```

What needs to be done??
In style I wrote everything that I tried..

Thank You

Comment: Even if I keep one at time still not working

Comment: That's right.  Many email clients (Outlook especially) have trouble supporting even some very basic CSS.  Depending on your version of Outlook, it is almost certainly impossible without resorting to images.